# How to stop a Thread by pressing a Java Swing button?

Tags: java, thread-safety, background-music

I created a Thread which plays a song from an implemented Runnable class(Soundtrack), I wanna stop it by pressing  my button(jMenuItem1ActionPerformed). I googled it & tried many ways to stop but failed I think in my case there's another way to do that. The following code below:

```
public static class Soundtrack implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
        File file = new File("SF.mp3");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        try{
            Player player = new Player(bis);
            player.play();
        }catch(JavaLayerException ex){}
    }catch(IOException e){}
    }
    }
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}    
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread background = new Thread(new Soundtrack());
    background.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you call player.stop() or something like that?

Comment: No i cant but there is player.close(), i cant call it like Player player = new Player();
player.close(); i had to put all the try and catch commands even though that still not working, i think that Player class is not from Java originally i added a new library JLayer 1.0.1 from http://www.javazoom.net/index.shtml in order to play mp3 files, these are the commands that i can set in player.:
close(); equals(Object o); getClass(); getPosition(); hashCode(); isComplete(); notify(); notifyAll(); play(); play(int i); toString(); wait(); wait(long l ); wait(long l, int i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna thank my sister for the solution:

```
public static class Soundtrack implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
        File file = new File("SF.mp3");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        try{
            Player player = new Player(bis);
            player.play();
        }catch(JavaLayerException ex){}
    }catch(IOException e){}
    }
    }
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
        background.stop();     
}                                          
private static Thread background;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    background = new Thread(new Soundtrack());
    background.start();
}
```

Comment: Correct. But you might benefit from learning about [executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) and `Future`.

Comment: Note: `Thread.stop()` is deprecated and it is recommended not to use `Thread.stop()`. In fact, I tried `Thread.stop()` for trying to stop the Swing thread but it wouldn't work.